# How to pass value from NSTabViewController to child view?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode-storyboard

I want to have tab menu in my Mac desktop application, each tab will show progresbarr (loading content from internet) and then loaded data. I want to use the same LoadingViewController in each page and only pass what data should be downloaded (according to tab user selected). How I can pass information from NSTabViewController to child ViewController?
This is how my storyboard looks:

[image: StoryBoard]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the storyboard "Document outline" pane (the collapsable one on the left that lists views, objects, etc), under the tab view controller there will be two objects labeled "Tab View Item". give each one of them an identifier.  (in the below example, they are "entriesTabItem" and "contactsTabItem".

Then, subclass TabViewController, and in that subclass, add something like the following in "viewDidLoad":

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var entryIndex = self.tabView.indexOfTabViewItemWithIdentifier("entriesTabItem")
    var entriesTVItem:NSTabViewItem = self.tabViewItems[entryIndex] as NSTabViewItem
    var entriesVC:EntryViewController? = entriesTVItem.viewController as EntryViewController?
    if (entriesVC != nil){
    entriesVC!.topTabView = self.tabView
        entriesVC!.topTabVC = self

    }

    var contactIndex = self.tabView.indexOfTabViewItemWithIdentifier("contactsTabItem")
    var contactTVItem:NSTabViewItem = self.tabViewItems[contactIndex] as NSTabViewItem
    var contactVC:ContactsViewController? = contactTVItem.viewController as ContactsViewController?
    if(contactVC != nil) {
        contactVC!.topTabView = self.tabView
        contactVC!.topTabVC = self

    }

}
```

In the code above, the view controllers could be of the same class instead of different as they are here, and you can pass whatever variables you wish.

I had to do this last week and it drove me crazy!

Comment: In other words, I have to subclass Tab View and add some extra code?

Comment: Not the tabView, but the TabViewController, which is different.  The tabView is a child of the TabViewController. The key is that you access the view controllers through the tabViewItems of the TabViewController. Using those, you can set any variables on the view controllers.

Comment: This will only work for items loaded when the tab view controller is loaded. From the ducumentation

Comment: The tab view controller lazily loads the views associated with each child view controller, creating them only after the corresponding tab is selected. When the tab view controller’s view is first displayed, only the view for the initially selected tab is loaded.
---
Perhaps better to do this stuff in tabItem(:didSelect) where the item should be loaded.